# Google Play Games - How to ask the user to create a gamerId account when signin in

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

When a user signs in my web based game with Google SignIn through a web browser, access is granted. However, when the app makes a call to the Games Services API, it returns the following error:

> User registration incomplete

If the user goes then to the Android Play Games app and creates a `Gamer ID` account, it works.

So, is there any way to tell the user to create a `Gamer ID` account when she signs in if she wants to proceed? Or, better, can Google redirect her to a page for that, complete the process and then come back to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gamer account (also sometimes informally referred to as Games lite account) can only be created on Android devices.  Once it is created it can be accessed from other platforms.

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if it could be done from the web too.

Comment: Are you sure? This is bad news! What if the user has only an iPhone device, then he will never have the chance to get a gamerid. Do you have an idea how big games handle it? Then please let us know.