# How to require google account with google+ upgrade? UserRegistrationIncomplete error

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, google-authentication

I am trying to use google play games services for web.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    GA = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: "...",
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games"});
});
```

I have two account, one with google+ and one without.
I can signin with both.

```
GA.signIn()
```

But when I try to submit score

```
gapi.client.games.scores.submit
```

The account without google+ returns error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "UserRegistrationIncomplete",
    "message": "User has not completed registration."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "User has not completed registration."
 }
}
```

I guess it means Account needs a google+ upgrade.

So, how can I require this when user signIn?

Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: I checked the internet about the error "UserRegistrationIncomplete" that you got and this is the closest thing that I found. [Google Play Games - How to ask the user to create a gamerId account when signin in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611584). So just check it if it can help you. About the Google + account, once you create a google account, you can access the Google + with it. So what you can do is to recommend that to use google account to sign in with your application.

Comment: Try to follow this [github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) and check if it is applicable in the application that you are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Google+ is no longer used by Play Game Services.  Starting last year, "Games Lite" was rolled out which makes players create a profile that is not publicly linked to their identity.  This was done to reduce the amount of friction created by having the player accept a permission consent before playing the game.  More info: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html

Unfortunately, the profile creation is Android only, so if the player has not signed into a game on Android, they will not have a profile and you will get this error.